# AsyncTask's onPostExecute method gets the same parameters

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I've got a **CardsParser** class which parses a web page and returns an **ArrayList** with WordCard objects. Then the objects are shown in a TextView.

The first request is always OK. But then I get the same result as it was for the first time. My TextView clears, new request runs and I always get objects from the first ArrayList.

I've found that **onPostExecute** method always gets the same ArrayList as a parameter, but I don't know why because I create new CardsParser every time and **doInBackground** method gets correct parameters.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText editText;
Button srchBtn;
TextView foundWords;
CardsParser cardsParser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    srchBtn = findViewById(R.id.srchBtn);
    srchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    foundWords = findViewById(R.id.foundWords);
    foundWords.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}

private class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<WordCard>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<WordCard> doInBackground(String... args) {
        cardsParser = new CardsParser();
        return cardsParser.parse(editText.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<WordCard> cards) {
        for (WordCard card : cards) {
            foundWords.append(card.word);
            foundWords.append("\n");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.srchBtn:
            foundWords.setText("");
            new AsyncRequest().execute();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if it helps, but avoid referencing UI objects from within doInBackground. Provide EditText string through AsyncTask's execute params.

Comment: @Lino I tried this but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. CardsParser class generated the same URL every time and that's why it didn't work properly.